# Conditional row grouping Ag-Grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there a way to enable row grouping, but only group rows when there are more than one values to be grouped.
I want to avoid having groups of only a single row. I don't think it makes sense to group those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to remove single children is by setting `removeSingleChildren=true`

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/

Comment: or groupRemoveSingleChildren: true in other versions

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to group **State** column of your data. But some of your row's **State column** value may not be exist/null. So you do not want to group these kind of rows. To achieve this **traverse your data source and assign State column value** to **null** or **undefined**. If you do this rows that have column value as null or undefined will not be grouped.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#unbalanced-groups

Comment: This is not default behaviour anymore since v30. You should explicitly set `:groupAllowUnbalanced="true"` to have columns with state `null` or `undefined` not grouped.